# Is there a way to make an object's variable set to another variable?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make an objects variable another set variable?

For example I want location on 'TutGrass'

[image: Location of tutgrass]

To always be set to CharacterX and CharacterY

[image]

So whenever the value of CharacterX and CharacterY changes the location of TutGrass will change aswell.

Comment: Just use properties instead.

Comment: Add code instead of screenshots, but in general you'd create a backing field that is shared by the properties.

Comment: Just use properties instead. -  Explain please

Comment: No, you can't just have an integer, change it and suddenly -wow your object changes something. Without context (Why you need it?) it doesn't make sence. But within some contxts it is possible that you create an observing class, to which you pass reference of your control and if anyone changes a property in this class (`characterX` for example), this cleaa will update your control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're can use properties to modify the value of Location:

```
public int CharacterX
{
  get
  {
    return Location.X;
  }
  set
  {
    Location = new Point(value, Location.Y);
  }
}
```

In this way the values of Location and Character are tied together (Location.X will hold the value in this example).  If you needed you could have another intermediate variable hold the value.  Usually it would be `private`.

In your code you can modify `Location.X` or `CharacterX` and they will both be updated:

```
Location.X = 5; //Sets the value of Location.X to 5
int testValue = CharacterX; //since CharacterX will return the value of Location.X testValue is assigned 5

CharacterX = 6;//Sets the value of Location.X to 6.  CharacterX never really holds a value, just assigns it to Location.X
```

Comment: hmmm sooooo that means i can do something like TutGrass.location.x = CharacterX.Location.X?

Comment: See my edits.  It might be helpful to your understanding if you put a break point within the `get` and `set`.

Comment: See my changes to the `set`.  You can't modify the `X` and `Y` of a `Point`, so I'm creating a new `Point` and assigning the appropriate values.

Comment: try `TutGrass.BringToFront()`